# jQuery click() still being triggered after .clickable class is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a click event assigned to a div of a particular class. When the click occurs, the class is removed from the div. However, you can still click the div and the `click()` event is triggered (even though the class has since been removed). Here's an example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="clickable">
  <p>Click me</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('clickable');
  $(this).addClass('not-clickable');
  alert('Clicked!');
});
```

I can see the classes are removed and added (as the colour of the text changed as per my CSS). However, you are still able to click the div multiple times and the `alert()` will still appear.

This also seems to occur in reverse; so if I add the `clickable` class to a div, the code in   `$('.clickable').click(function() {...});` doesn't run (but visually, the div changes as per the new styles).

How can I make it so that the click events match up to the classes, even after jQuery adds/removes the `clickable` class?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you attach an event handler to a DOM element, it stays intact.
The class is just a way to reference the element, and changing the class will not unbind the event handlers, for that you will have to manually unbind the handler, and if using jQuery 1.7+ `on()` and `off()` is the way to go :

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('clickable').addClass('not-clickable').off('click');
});
```

this would make the element clickable only once, and you could just use the built in `one()` function instead, as that will unbind the handler automagically after the first click :

```
$('.clickable').one('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('clickable').addClass('not-clickable');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I can see what happens now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

```
$(document.body).delegate('.clickable', 'click', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('clickable');
    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

From jQuery version 1.7 `delegate()` is superseded by the `on()`

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.clickable', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('clickable');
    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Or

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('clickable').off('click');
    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Also you can use method `one()` - it's equal to bind, but occurs once

```
$('.clickable').one('click', function(e){
    alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('clickable');
  $(this).addClass('not-clickable');
  alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.clickable').live('click',function() {
  $(this).removeClass('clickable');//remove the class
  $(this).unbind('click');//to remove the click event
  $(this).addClass('not-clickable');
  alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

unbind click event - like `$(this).unbind('click');'` 
Try this

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('clickable');
  $(this).addClass('not-clickable');
  $(this).unbind('click');'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understand of even assignment is a bit wrong.
Please read your code

```
$('.clickable').click(function()
```

1. Find **element** with the class '.clickable'
2. Assign onclick handler to the **element**

See, it's the element that get's handler, not the class name.
You need to remove the handler. For that you can try:

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('clickable');
    $(this).addClass('not-clickable');
    alert('Clicked!');
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call click event only once use jQuery `one` function to bind events it will destroy itself.

```
$('.clickable').one('click',function() {
   $(this).removeClass('clickable');//remove the class
   $(this).addClass('not-clickable');
   alert('Clicked!');
});
```