# Adding class onclick and then attaching different handler to that class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

My question is very similar to this one: [jQuery click() still being triggered after .clickable class is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984067/jquery-click-still-being-triggered-after-clickable-class-is-removed)

I have an unordered list and two different functions that I want to fire depending on the class of the list item. In my app I'm using Glyphicons so that when the user clicks an icon, I call an AJAX process and change the icon to something like 'undo'. Then I want to attach another handler to just that undo class and call a different AJAX function when that icon is clicked. These are rows in a report, for what it's worth.

Here is a simple example:
If the user clicks the link the first time, I want to change the class and bind a new event to that class. I am (slowly) learning that the event binds to the element and not the class, so I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkolden/UFcm2/4/

My HTML:

```
<p>After each click, I want to change the class for the clicked li and attach a new    event handler to that new class</p>
<ul>
    <li class='Action1'>Item A - click me</li>
    <li class='Action1'>Item B - click me</li>
    <li class='Action1'>Item C - click me</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.Action1').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('Action1');
    $(this).addClass('Action2');
    var text = $(this).text().split('-');
    alert('Action 1 was fired and the class of ' + text[0]  + 'should now be Action2');
});

$('.Action2').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('Action2');
    $(this).addClass('Action1');
    alert('Action 2 was fired');
});
```

Is this possible? Any clues are greatly appreciated and apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should/can do that with [**`event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), since you are removing/adding classes dynamically.

Try,

```
$(document).on('click','.Action1', function() {
```

and

```
$(document).on('click','.Action2', function() {
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UFcm2/5/)

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! I'll read up on event delegation but your example is exactly what I needed!