# JQuery fix for disabling button

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to disable the "Next" button until each of the sliders is used, I am not sure why it is un-disabling the button when clicking on the same slider that is no longer class="not-clicked".

[JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/37sLLh5h/) (it looks a little messy here but works)

```
var count = 0;
$('.not-clicked').click(function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('not-clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  count++;
  if( count > foodCount )
  {
    var nextBtn = document.getElementsByName("commit")[0];
    nextBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: You can use the *on() and off()* methods to attach/detach the event. *$('.slider-fill').on('click','.not-clicked',function(e)*  and you won't have the problem. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984067/jquery-click-still-being-triggered-after-clickable-class-is-removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for $('.not-clicked').length to be 0 :

```
$('.not-clicked').click(function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass('not-clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');

  if ($('.not-clicked').length == 0) {
   var nextBtn = document.getElementsByName("commit")[0];
   nextBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
});
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/hqL6a146/