# My onclick is attached to a class that is being removed within the same function. Why is it still being triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have an onclick event triggered by the class "tile1". Within that function I use "classList.remove("tile1")" so how come it is being triggered a second time if I click on the element that had the class "tile1"?

There is a lot of css information here but I do not believe any of it is relevant to what is causing a problem but I have included it so that you can easily copy and paste the code for yourself.

Any help is much appreciated.

```js
var galleryContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("galleryContainer");
var category = document.getElementsByClassName("category");
var subCat = document.getElementsByClassName("subCat");
var tile = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
var tile1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tile1");
var tileImg = document.getElementsByClassName("tileImg");
var galleryWindow = document.getElementsByClassName("galleryWindow");
var albumEntry = document.getElementsByClassName("albumEntry");
var albumEntryImg = document.getElementsByClassName("albumEntryImg");
// POSSIBLE ISSUE (next two lines)
for(var index = 0; index < tile1.length; index++) {
    tile1[index].onclick = function() {
     
        //SUBCAT1a
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var a = 0; a < subCat.length; a++) {
                subCat[a].classList.remove("subCat1");
                subCat[a].classList.remove("subCat2");
                subCat[a].classList.remove("subCat3");
                subCat[a].classList.add("subCat1a");
                subCat[a].style.transition = "linear 200ms";
            }
        }, 0);

        //SUBCAT
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var b = 0; b < subCat.length; b++) {
                subCat[b].classList.remove("subCat1");
                subCat[b].classList.remove("subCat1a");
                subCat[b].classList.remove("subCat3");
                subCat[b].classList.add("subCat2");
                subCat[b].style.transition = "linear 1000ms";
            }
        }, 1500);

        //GALLERY CONTAINER
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var c = 0; c < galleryContainer.length; c++) {
                galleryContainer[c].classList.remove("galleryContainer1");
                galleryContainer[c].classList.remove("galleryContainer3");
                galleryContainer[c].classList.add("galleryContainer2");
                galleryContainer[c].style.transition = "linear 500ms";
            }
        }, 1000);

        //CATEGORY
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var d = 0; d < category.length; d++) {
                category[d].classList.remove("category1");
                category[d].classList.remove("category2");
                category[d].classList.remove("category3");
                category[d].classList.add("category1a");
                category[d].style.transition = "linear 500ms";
            }
        }, 500);

        //CATEGORY
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var e = 0; e < category.length; e++) {
                category[e].classList.remove("category1");
                category[e].classList.remove("category1a");
                category[e].classList.remove("category3");
                category[e].classList.add("category2");
                //category[e].style.transition = "linear 0s";
            }
        }, 500);

        // POSSIBLE ISSUE (next nine lines)
        //TILE
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var f = 0; f < tile.length; f++) {
                tile[f].classList.remove("tile1");
                tile[f].classList.remove("tile3");
                tile[f].classList.add("tile2");
                //tile[e].style.transition = "linear 0s";
            }
        }, 500);


        //TILEIMG
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var g = 0; g < tileImg.length; g++) {
                tileImg[g].classList.remove("tileImg1");
                tileImg[g].classList.remove("tileImg3");
                tileImg[g].classList.add("tileImg2");
                tileImg[g].style.transition = "linear 500ms";
            }
        }, 500);


        //GALLERY WINDOW
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var h = 0; h < galleryWindow.length; h++) {
                galleryWindow[h].classList.remove("galleryWindow1");
                galleryWindow[h].classList.remove("galleryWindow3");
                galleryWindow[h].classList.add("galleryWindow2");
                //galleryWindow[h].style.transition = "opacity linear 5000ms";
            }
        }, 1800);

        //ALBUM ENTRY CONTAINER
        setTimeout(function(){
             for(var i = 0; albumEntry.length; i++) {
                 albumEntry[i].classList.remove("albumEntry1");
                 albumEntry[i].classList.remove("albumEntry3");
                 albumEntry[i].classList.add("albumEntry2");
             }
        }, 1800);

        //ALBUM ENTRY IMG
        setTimeout(function(){
             for(var j = 0; albumEntryImg.length; j++) {
                 albumEntryImg[j].classList.remove("albumEntryImg1");
                 albumEntryImg[j].classList.remove("albumEntryImg3");
                 albumEntryImg[j].classList.add("albumEntryImg2");
             }
        }, 1800);
    }   
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* ////////// STEP 1 ////////// */

.galleryContainer1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 1vw;
}

.category1 {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
}

.category1 h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.6vw;
    left: 1vw;
    
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    padding: 0px 1vw;
}

.subCat1 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5vw;
    
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 1vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tile1:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.tile1 h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1vw;
    
    user-select: none;
    cursor: inherit;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 
        0px 0px 5px #000;
}

.tileImg1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 6vw;
}

#natureText {left: 3vw;}

.galleryWindow1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.galleryWindow1 h1 {
    display: none;
    color: #f0f;
}

.albumEntry1 {
    display: none;
}

.albumEntryImg1 {
    display: none;
}

/* ///// STEP 1a (transitional step) ///// */

.category1a:first-of-type {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
    
    height: 15vw;
}

.category1a {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
    
    height: 28vw;
}

.subCat1a {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5vw;
    
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    opacity: 0;
}

/* ////////// STEP 2 ////////// */

.galleryContainer2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 20vw;
    
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 1vw;
}

.category2:first-of-type {
    /*min-height: 190px;*/
    height: 14vw;
}

.category2 {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
    
    /*min-height: 360px;*/
    height: 27vw;
}

.category2 h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.6vw;
    left: 1vw;
    
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    padding: 0px 1vw;
}

.subCat2 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5vw;
    
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.tile2 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0vw;
    user-select: none;
}

.tile2 h4 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.2vw;
    
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tile2 h4:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.tileImg2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.8vw;
    /*top: 11px;*/
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 0vw;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test 5 - transitions</title>
    <link href="css/T5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="galleryContainer galleryContainer1">
        <div class="category category1">
            <h3>TYPE:</h3>
            <div class="subCat subCat1">
                <div class="tile tile1">
                    <div>
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="tileText tileText1" id="natureText">Nature</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="galleryWindow galleryWindow1">
        <h1>TEST:</h1>
    </section>
    <script src="js/T5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery click() still being triggered after .clickable class is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984067/jquery-click-still-being-triggered-after-clickable-class-is-removed)

Comment: It is recommended to put some codes to your post because the users can help you better. Not putting entire your project. please put a little sample of your issue. it should more easy to read and answer.

Comment: because events are added to the elements directly, it does not have some magic logic that know when elements are changed.

Comment: Well, the click is not triggered by the class and the class is not even related to the listening, what you are actually doing is using the class to select an element list and then adding an event listener to this elements you selected. To remove the listener you can use `elm.removeEventListener(myHandler)`

Comment: I may be wrong (because read your code too fast), but you append onclick to element that you get by class. so even after you remove that class from element the onclick event is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When registering event listeners, you are registering an *element*. As long as that element has a, for example, click event listener attached, the event listener's callback will be fired every time that element is clicked. That element can have classes added and/or removed, and the event listener wouldn't be affected. Remember, you've only used the class to *find* the element you want to attach an event listener to. Once you've found it, removing the class you used to find it is irrelevant.

To remove an element listener, use `removeEventListener` and pass the same reference to the callback used to register the event listener.

Since you've used `onclick`, you can just set the function reference to `null`.

...
`tile[f].onclick = null;`
...

```js
var galleryContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("galleryContainer");
var category = document.getElementsByClassName("category");
var subCat = document.getElementsByClassName("subCat");
var tile = document.getElementsByClassName("tile");
var tile1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tile1");
var tileImg = document.getElementsByClassName("tileImg");
var galleryWindow = document.getElementsByClassName("galleryWindow");
var albumEntry = document.getElementsByClassName("albumEntry");
var albumEntryImg = document.getElementsByClassName("albumEntryImg");
// POSSIBLE ISSUE (next two lines)
for(var index = 0; index < tile1.length; index++) {
    tile1[index].onclick = function() {
     
        //SUBCAT1a
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var a = 0; a < subCat.length; a++) {
                subCat[a].classList.remove("subCat1");
                subCat[a].classList.remove("subCat2");
                subCat[a].classList.remove("subCat3");
                subCat[a].classList.add("subCat1a");
                subCat[a].style.transition = "linear 200ms";
            }
        }, 0);

        //SUBCAT
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var b = 0; b < subCat.length; b++) {
                subCat[b].classList.remove("subCat1");
                subCat[b].classList.remove("subCat1a");
                subCat[b].classList.remove("subCat3");
                subCat[b].classList.add("subCat2");
                subCat[b].style.transition = "linear 1000ms";
            }
        }, 1500);

        //GALLERY CONTAINER
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var c = 0; c < galleryContainer.length; c++) {
                galleryContainer[c].classList.remove("galleryContainer1");
                galleryContainer[c].classList.remove("galleryContainer3");
                galleryContainer[c].classList.add("galleryContainer2");
                galleryContainer[c].style.transition = "linear 500ms";
            }
        }, 1000);

        //CATEGORY
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var d = 0; d < category.length; d++) {
                category[d].classList.remove("category1");
                category[d].classList.remove("category2");
                category[d].classList.remove("category3");
                category[d].classList.add("category1a");
                category[d].style.transition = "linear 500ms";
            }
        }, 500);

        //CATEGORY
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var e = 0; e < category.length; e++) {
                category[e].classList.remove("category1");
                category[e].classList.remove("category1a");
                category[e].classList.remove("category3");
                category[e].classList.add("category2");
                //category[e].style.transition = "linear 0s";
            }
        }, 500);

        // POSSIBLE ISSUE (next nine lines)
        //TILE
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var f = 0; f < tile.length; f++) {
                tile[f].classList.remove("tile1");
                tile[f].onclick = null;
                tile[f].classList.remove("tile3");
                tile[f].classList.add("tile2");
                //tile[e].style.transition = "linear 0s";
            }
        }, 500);


        //TILEIMG
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var g = 0; g < tileImg.length; g++) {
                tileImg[g].classList.remove("tileImg1");
                tileImg[g].classList.remove("tileImg3");
                tileImg[g].classList.add("tileImg2");
                tileImg[g].style.transition = "linear 500ms";
            }
        }, 500);


        //GALLERY WINDOW
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var h = 0; h < galleryWindow.length; h++) {
                galleryWindow[h].classList.remove("galleryWindow1");
                galleryWindow[h].classList.remove("galleryWindow3");
                galleryWindow[h].classList.add("galleryWindow2");
                //galleryWindow[h].style.transition = "opacity linear 5000ms";
            }
        }, 1800);

        //ALBUM ENTRY CONTAINER
        setTimeout(function(){
             for(var i = 0; albumEntry.length; i++) {
                 albumEntry[i].classList.remove("albumEntry1");
                 albumEntry[i].classList.remove("albumEntry3");
                 albumEntry[i].classList.add("albumEntry2");
             }
        }, 1800);

        //ALBUM ENTRY IMG
        setTimeout(function(){
             for(var j = 0; albumEntryImg.length; j++) {
                 albumEntryImg[j].classList.remove("albumEntryImg1");
                 albumEntryImg[j].classList.remove("albumEntryImg3");
                 albumEntryImg[j].classList.add("albumEntryImg2");
             }
        }, 1800);
    }   
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* ////////// STEP 1 ////////// */

.galleryContainer1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 1vw;
}

.category1 {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
}

.category1 h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.6vw;
    left: 1vw;
    
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    padding: 0px 1vw;
}

.subCat1 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5vw;
    
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tile1 {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 1vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tile1:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.tile1 h4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.1vw;
    
    user-select: none;
    cursor: inherit;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 
        0px 0px 5px #000;
}

.tileImg1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 6vw;
}

#natureText {left: 3vw;}

.galleryWindow1 {
    display: flex;
    width: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.galleryWindow1 h1 {
    display: none;
    color: #f0f;
}

.albumEntry1 {
    display: none;
}

.albumEntryImg1 {
    display: none;
}

/* ///// STEP 1a (transitional step) ///// */

.category1a:first-of-type {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
    
    height: 15vw;
}

.category1a {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
    
    height: 28vw;
}

.subCat1a {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5vw;
    
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    opacity: 0;
}

/* ////////// STEP 2 ////////// */

.galleryContainer2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 20vw;
    
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 1vw;
}

.category2:first-of-type {
    /*min-height: 190px;*/
    height: 14vw;
}

.category2 {
    border: 0.4vw solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    margin: 1vw;
    
    /*min-height: 360px;*/
    height: 27vw;
}

.category2 h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.6vw;
    left: 1vw;
    
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    
    padding: 0px 1vw;
}

.subCat2 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.5vw;
    
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.tile2 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0vw;
    user-select: none;
}

.tile2 h4 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.2vw;
    
    font-size: 1.3vw;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tile2 h4:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.tileImg2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.8vw;
    /*top: 11px;*/
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 0vw;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test 5 - transitions</title>
    <link href="css/T5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="galleryContainer galleryContainer1">
        <div class="category category1">
            <h3>TYPE:</h3>
            <div class="subCat subCat1">
                <div class="tile tile1">
                    <div>
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                        <img class="tileImg tileImg1" src="../../Image Bank/Location/London/1 london-people-sky-34208.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="tileText tileText1" id="natureText">Nature</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="galleryWindow galleryWindow1">
        <h1>TEST:</h1>
    </section>
    <script src="js/T5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```